# Get column value of command's output in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt

Need Help,

I want to retrieve the value of column 'IMAGE' to a variable in windows command prompt. Here its value is "192.XXX.XX.X:XXXX/applicationtest:36" which i want to assign to a variable.

Output of my command(docker ps -f "name=AbcApp"):

**CONTAINER_ID**   |    **IMAGE**
63c2d768cca0       |   192.XXX.XX.X:XXXX/applicationtest:36

I did check answers to few questions that are already here but still didn't figure out how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: There aren't any columns or other formatting meta data, this is plain text output. You are going to have to parse the information yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with c, then use:

```
char var[128];
char line[128];      // or any other bufsize you want
FILE * pipe = popen("your command here", "r");

if(pipe)
{
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, pipe)
    {
        sscanf(line, "data-specif", var);
    }
    pclose(pipe);
}
```

> In place of `data-specif` substitute the data-type-specifier (parse
>   the line accordingly) and in place of `var`, the value you need to
>   store.

For example: `Satya Pawan 17` should be parsed as `%s %s %d`.